# Linq statement to get a string that is not substring of a longer string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a long string S that may contain pattern `p1, p2, p3, ....;`

All patterns are put in a `MatchCollection` object

I would like to do something like

```
string ret=p_n if !(S.Contains(p_n))
```

I write a for loop to do this

```
foreach(string p in PatternList)
{
   s=(!S.contain(p.valus))?p.value:"";
}
```

I would like to know a LINQ statement to make my cocde more elgant.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to get the list of matched patterns, the last match, or a list the size of matchcollection that returns a bunch of "" for the non-matches and the match value for matches?

Comment: I think your question title is a little mis-leading.  You indicate that all patterns are put in a MatchCollection but ask for a LINQ statement to check for a string that is not part of a longer string in the title.  p.valus in the body of your question indicates you're really looking at a Match from a MatchCollection and not a string that is not a substring of a longer string.

Answer (score 4):

```
var patterns = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

var misses = patterns.Where(s => !longString.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "12345asdfasdf12w3e412354w12341523142341235123";

        string patternString = "one1234554321asdf";


        MatchCollection p_ns = Regex.Matches(patternString, "one|12345|54321|asdf");

        var nonMatches = (from p_n in p_ns.Cast<Match>()
                          where !S.Contains(p_n.Value)
                          select p_n.Value);

        foreach (string nonMatch in nonMatches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nonMatch);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Or to use Justin's method from his answer you could also use the below variation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "12345asdfasdf12w3e412354w12341523142341235123";

        string patternString = "one1234554321asdf";


        MatchCollection p_ns = Regex.Matches(patternString, "one|12345|54321|asdf");

        var nonMatches = p_ns.Cast<Match>().Where(s => !S.Contains(s.Value));

        foreach (Match nonMatch in nonMatches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nonMatch.Value);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6";

        List<string> PatternList = new List<string>();

        PatternList.Add("p2");
        PatternList.Add("p5");
        PatternList.Add("p9");

        foreach (string s in PatternList.Where(x => !S.Contains(x)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```